# UIButton style gone after segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I'm trying to fix a problem that does not make any sense to me. 
I'm applying a style to 3 of my buttons. When I click another one, there is a segue. When I dismiss the viewController, the style is not applied to my 3 previous buttons..until I click again ! I thought it was my configuration with line code that was wrong so I've deleted every customizations.

I directly configure buttons from the interface builder.

Here it my segue code even if I think it's not useful.

```
- (IBAction)addContact:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FriendsToAddFriends" sender:sender];
}
```

I've added some picture to show my problem :

[image: Screenshots]

The strangest part is when I'm back to the first page, when I click **without release** my click, the style comes back. It's the same for the whole 3 buttons.

I don't have any other idea to fix it. Does someone have ?

Thank you a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with this code :

```
for (UIButton* button in buttons) {
   [button.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentNatural];
}
```

I applied it on each following methods :

`viewWillDisappear`
`viewWillAppear`

I still don't know why this alignment change when the view will disappear.

It seems working for now.
I hope it will help someone else.